# Reference in documentation to ->>>[_, _ ] and ~>

Tags: scala, scalaz

Where can I find the reference in Lang specification or any blog how to read these constructions:

```
trait GenericFunctor[->>[_, _ ], ->>>[_, _ ], F[_]] { 
  def fmap[A, B](f: A ->> B): F[A] ->>> F[B]
}
```

or

```
trait Category[~>[_, _ ]] {
  def compose[A, B, C](f: B ~> C)(g: A ~> B): A ~> C 
  def id[A]: A ~> A 
}
```

if it's a Type name - then the code  `F[A] ->>> F[B]` shouldn't be compilable, but it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
trait GenericFunctor[->>[_, _], ->>>[_, _], F[_]] { 
  def fmap[A, B](f: A ->> B): F[A] ->>> F[B]
}
```

Scala allows symbols in identifiers. Let's replace the symbolic identifiers with alphanumeric ones.

```
trait GenericFunctor[M[_, _], N[_, _], F[_]] { 
  def fmap[A, B](f: A M B): F[A] N F[B]
}
```

Scala provides infix type notation for binary type constructors. In other words, `A M B` is same as `M[A, B]`. Let's rewrite above code without that sugar.

```
trait GenericFunctor[M[_, _], N[_, _], F[_]] { 
  def fmap[A, B](f: M[A, B]): N[F[A], F[B]]
}
```

Similary, the `Category` definition in your question can be rewritten as:

```
trait Category[F[_, _]] {
  def compose[A, B, C](f: F[B, C])(g: F[A, B]): F[A, C]
  def id[A]: F[A, A] 
}
```

Is it clear now?

Comment: +1 I had to do this all the time when learning Ocaml. That language like Scala has ridiculous amount of syntactic sugar (not bad a thing but makes it difficult for people to learn).